# Wildfly Randomly gets killed

Tags: linux, debian, wildfly8

I'm with a weird problem that i tried everything and i couldn't solve it.

I have a instance of Wildfly 8.2 running a JavaEE application that controls a CallCenter, this application use like 2 ~ 8 gb memory depends on how much peopple are working, the application controls the telephony, and a web interface for configuration / reports and other sutffs.

Randomly the wildfly gets killed and i see in console the following message:

```
*** JBossAS process XXXX received kill signal ***
```

And i need to start it again.

I read about that probably being the linux OOM Killer that was killing my process, so i set in the /proc/wildfly_pid/oom_adj the value -17, as i read in documentation it makes the oom killer ignores the process, but it seems to don't work, and wildfly keeps getting killed, i did a cron job to configure the oom_adj each 1 min, and checked it, was configured correct, but nothing helps.

I was monitoring the application and the memory was like on 3 gb and its get killed, it works for some hours but randomly gets killed.

I don't know what to do, i'm using Debian 7.8 on and server that is from my client with 16gb memory and Wildfly 8.2 in standalone mode with the following java opts

```
-server -Xms256m -Xmx8192m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

A link for the dmesg output [dmesg](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17155314/dmesg.txt)

Comment: Wildfly run as a service, and the syslog/messages just show the kernel adjusting latency, no killed process but it goes down.

Comment: I have no server.log, just /var/log/wildfly/console.log is that it?

Comment: What exactly should I look out for in there? It is too big, theres no "killed process"... Is there anything I should for specifically?

Comment: I too face this issue..No error logs at the backend. Only receives " has received kill signal from JBOSS." log..I again monitor the memory consumption, it was 80%..Any cause for this?